# how to jquery for storing value into db (textbox that id's are incremented by loop )

Tags: jquery

i have a multiple text boxes according to a persons accounts. when page is loading that retrieve accounts for each accounts text box will be provided. when clicking or changing text box that value should stored into db. i tried but it is not working. help me some one

```
for (var n = 1; n <= "@Model.AnnualBudget.Accounts.Count()"; n++) {

            if (("'#AccPlan' + n") > 0) {
                $("'#AccPlan'+n").change(function () {
                    var customerAccountID = $("'#AccId'+n").val();
                    var budgetAmount = $("'#AccPlan'+n").val();

                    $.getJSON("/Statements/UpdateAccountBudgetValue",
                         { accountID: customerAccountID, budgetAmount: budgetAmount },
                    function (result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: _What_ isn't working? Is there an error on the client? Are you seeing the request hit your back-end?

Comment: @pdoherty926 for fixed id its working by loop its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dW5Uv/

```
        for(var n = 1; n <= 6; n++) {
            $("#AccPlan"+n).change(function () {
                var budgetAmount = $(this).val();
                alert(budgetAmount);
            });
        }
```

The way you are concatenating ID's is not correct.

Comment: Then Something is wrong in the Backend . Log the reply you are getting after the request and see using Inspect in Firefox or Chrome or use Firebug .

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function () {

        var TextBoxNo = $(this).attr('id');
        var customerAccountID = $("#AccId" + TextBoxNo).val();
        var budgetAmount = $(this).val();

                $.getJSON("/Statements/UpdateAccountBudgetValue",
                     { accountID: customerAccountID, budgetAmount: budgetAmount },
                function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {                            
                    }
                });
            });
       });
```